# random rotation in sprite kit

Tags: rotation, sprite

hi guys I have this code for a character on my screen now I want to rotate it in y direction like a person looking at its left or right based on random time interval. 
but my code is not working does anyone has any clues where am I making a mistake? by the way please don't look for any random time as I am very newbie and don't know an SKAction which does the rotation based on zRotation.

```
   - (void) RandomRotator {
          _Enemy.zRotation += 180;
          _Enemy.zRotation -= 180;
          SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:2.5];
          [_Enemy runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait]]];
    }
```

now what exactly I mean by that is like the picture Above:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the angle is measured in radians not degrees.
So instead of `_Enemy.zRotation += 180;` it should be `_Enemy.zRotation += M_PI;`.

At the moment your rotation isn't actually animating or doing anything. You have to call an action specifically to rotate.
The only action your character is running is the wait action.

I assume you want to animate the characters rotation, in which case try:

```
float duration = 1.0;
SKAction *rotateForward = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:duration];
SKAction *rotateBackward = [SKAction rotateByAngle:-M_PI duration:duration];
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:2.5];
[_Enemy runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[rotateForward, wait, rotateBackward, wait]]];`
```

If you want the enemy to wait a random amount of time between rotations; and also keep repeating this animation, you could do something like:

```
- (void)randomRotator {
    SKAction *rotateForward = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:1.0 + drand48()]; 
    // Where 1.0 + drand48() returns a float between 1.0 and 2.0
    SKAction *rotateBackward = [SKAction rotateByAngle:-M_PI duration:1.0 + drand48()];
    SKAction *wait1 = [SKAction waitForDuration:2.0 + drand48()];
    SKAction *wait2 = [SKAction waitForDuration:2.0 + drand48()];
    [_Enemy runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[rotateForward, wait1, rotateBackward, wait2]] completion:^{
        [self randomRotator]; // Call the method again, to repeat rotation
    }];
}
```

I hope that makes sense. I'm not sure if I have fully understood your question.